# IntelliJ and svn:ignore

Tags: java, svn, intellij-idea

IntelliJ does not seem to honour `svn:ignore`

I use Maven to generate classes based on an annotation processor. These classes are compiled into target/generated-sources/apt

I add an `svn:ignore` to the target directory (placed in the parent of target) but IntelliJ still wants to commit the directory.

When I select Subversion -> Commit this directory is selected to be committed.

I cannot use the exclude option in the module properties as this directory includes source code, so it must not be excluded, it must just not be checked in. Nor can I use a global filter as it's not any specific extension I want to ignore, it is a whole directory and all the sub-directories.

BTW, I'm using IntelliJ 10.5 running on Ubuntu and SVN 1.6

Comment: Just to make sure: does the parent directory of target have the svn property `svn:ignore`, with the value `target`?

Comment: correct, that's what I've done

Answer (score 5):

With the setting `Settings > Version Control > Confirmation > When files are created` set to `Add silently`, the file is directly added to the subversion local repository. The command `ignore` of the context menu is afterwards grayed out.

I found no solution but to change this setting, delete the file and create it again.

Comment: Finally a suggestion that worked for my case! You just saved my laptop. I was ready to throw it from the 4th floor. Many many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Setting of ignored files in IntelliJ IDEA (`Settings` | `Version Control` | `Ignored Files`) doesn't work for svn repo. This variant applicable as IDEA configuration only.

To configure this for svn repo you need to define `svn:ignore` property. To do that you need select folder location where placed ignored files or folders (usually it's root project directory). Next on top menu choose `VCS > Subversion > Edit properties`. Then you can see `SVN Properties` dialog, you need define `svn:ignore` property with value of ignored files or directories (separated with enter).

Comment: You can also use autoprops or global ignores.

Comment: (Settings | Version Control | Ignored Files) has disappeared. It's not in 2019.2 :-(

Comment: This basically tells me that the parent folder is not in the repo. :>{